# Unable to launch Jmeter of version 5.4.1 on Mac

Tags: jmeter

Clicking on the JMeter batch file, the below error is thrown in the console log

> Error: Could not find or load main class 6.bin....docs.images.jmeter_square.png
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 6/bin////docs/images/jmeter_square/png
> logout
> Saving session...
> ...copying shared history...
> ...saving history...truncating history files...
> ...completed.

[Process completed]

I've tried changing my folder location and no luck.
Note: I'm able to launch JMeter 5.3 on the same mac machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a broken/incomplete download, [verify the integrity of the downloaded JMeter archive](https://www.apache.org/info/verification.html) by comparing its checksum with the [KEYS](https://downloads.apache.org/jmeter/KEYS) from JMeter website

Also as per [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans) article it's possible to install JMeter using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager like:

```
brew install jmeter
```

or if you want the plugins as well:

```
brew install jmeter --with-plugins
```

More information: [Run JMeter with plugins in macOS](https://medium.com/@sdanerib/run-jmeter-with-plugins-in-macos-8a6654fc0b38)

Comment: After running "brew install jmeter" I could launch JMeter without errors. Thank you!